# How to save the state of a checkbox placed into the PluginDocumentSettingPanel

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

How and where can I store the sate of a checkbox component that I have placed into PluginDocumentSettingPanel?

```
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;
const { useSelect } = wp.data;
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { useState } = wp.element;
const { CheckboxControl } = wp.components;

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    // Retrict this component to pages only
    const postType = useSelect( select => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType() );
    if ( 'page' !== postType ) { return null; }

    const [ isChecked, setChecked ] = useState( false );

    return (
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
            name="my-custom-panel"
            title="my-custom-panel-title"
            className="my-custom-panel"
        >
            <CheckboxControl
                 label="my-label"
                 checked={ isChecked }
                 onChange={ setChecked }
            />
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    );
}

registerPlugin( 'my-custom-panel', { render: MyComponent } );
```

The component is functional but the state is not saved. What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the state callback in the listener. This should work.

```
<CheckboxControl
   label="my-label"
   checked={ isChecked }
   onChange={ () => setChecked( ! isChecked ) }
/>
```